# Rails save record draft with dummy variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

So I need more alongs the lines of just advice than actual code here, but this is my situation:

I have a model that requires two associations - an author and a user.  However, I want it to be possible for authors to create the record with the possibility that it will later be "claimed" by a user created later.

The best solution that I've come up with is to user some sort of "Dummy User" association for those cases, but it feels hacky.

Any better suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making the associations *not* required? Are the associations enforced with validations? How about relaxing the validations instead? So there would be no user association persisted until the time it is claimed.